# Make dropdownList default value with case-insensitive - Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to use Yii dropdownlist, dropdown array values getting from database,

Dropdown values:

**oui,non**

but user provides value as **"Oui"**

```
CHtml::dropDownList("Educated:, "Oui",$values,array())
```

**where $values = array("oui","non")**

so the default value is not get selected in dropdownlist because of case-sensitive.

please can anyone give me an idea to handle this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert all DB values and user provided value to lower-case like below.

```
CHtml::dropDownList("Educated:", strtolower("Oui"), array_map('strtolower',$values),array());
```